# How to sort a csv file alphabetically in shell scrit?

Tags: linux, shell, alphabetical-sort

I'm trying to make a shell script that its only function is showing as output the content of a csv file in alphabetical order, the thing is I know I should do it with the sort command and I've tried the next thing:

```
#!bin/bash

sort cars.csv
```

Sorry if this script seems useless (I know you could just do this with the command console) but this is for a college bigger project and I don't have any idea what am I doing wrong.

Thank you all

Comment: Your script is correct, so where's your problem?

Comment: Possibly the `#!bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/bash` depending on how you are running the script. But what do you find doesn't work? What happens when you run it?

Comment: What result do you get and how it differs from what you expected?

Comment: It was just that stupid error, I should have written #! /bin/bash instead of #!bin/bash. Sorry for bothering and thank you all!

Comment: If it is **really** a csv file, you can not use `sort`, because a csv file can contain embedded meta-characters: For instance, fields which themselves contain the record separator, or contain a newline, are enclosed in quotes, and `sort` obviously can't handle those.